# googlemaps cannot find the icon address

Tags: google-maps

If I put my icon image in the directory where the HTML page is the following works.

```
var img = new google.maps.MarkerImage("icon.png");
```

It also works if I put it in a folder.

```
var img = new google.maps.MarkerImage("foldername/icon.png");
```

But I cannot get the following to work.

```
var img = new google.maps.MarkerImage("C:/foldername/icon.png");
```

How do you write the address when the image is not within the folder where the page is?

Answer (score 0):

The URL of the icon must be publicly available on the web (your C: drive isn't).

Something like: `http://<yourdomainname>/foldername/icon.png` should work.

Comment: Are you sure? It works when the image is within the same folder structure as the HTML page. And that is definately not public.